# Need help with a grab Shader

Tags: shaders, glsl

How can I make grab Shader similar to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GrabPass.html in GLSL.

The idea, is that you grab exact pixels from background (ex. from composited renderTarget) and put on rendered object. So it's like 100% transparency, because it always has the pixels right behind. Later if you disort the pixels, can give very cool effects like https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mdc3Rl.

SO far I have texture of background (plane to renderTarget), and object cube right before it. My vertex shader for cube is `gl_Position = WVP * spos;` and I have no idea how do the frag shader to copy the pixels from background. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my setup it was as easy as:

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize;

fragColor.rgb = texture(background, uv.xy).rgb;
fragColor.a = 1.0;
```